# Re-map a "dead" button on remote to something useful in Kodi

Tags: remote, keyboard

I'm a complete noob as regards Linux, but I've got a Pi 3B that's currently only set up to run Kodi under LibreElec. It's actually got *three* 2.4GHz IR remotes (*and* a Bluetooth keyboard) connected, and they all seem to work together perfectly happily.

It turns out that unless I need to type actual *text* (search strings, for example) I can do just about everything I want using this really cheap one, which I find far more ergonomic than the others...

[image]

BUT it seems the "hamburger" button (the one with three lines, above the "house/home" button in the pic) isn't recognised at all in Kodi. And I've come to realise that if I could only remap that key so it was interpreted as keyboard character **C** (to invoke *context menus*), that would vastly improve my user experience.

I have a Win10 desktop PC that I can install the IR remote on if I need to use a utility to find out what scan-code(s) are generated by that hamburger button. I can also use the PC to explore / amend files on the 16Gb card the Pi boots from, but I don't know how to do this using the Pi itself.

Is there any way I can remap that button to do what I want?

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/using-an-ir-remote-with-a-raspberry-pi-media-center/lirc?view=all

Comment: @Steve Robillard: Thanks for that link. I can "sorta" understand what they're saying there, but to be honest I think I need something a bit simpler.